# Why does FFMPEG always make large WebM files?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, webm

I'm trying to encode my movies into WebM:

```
ffmpeg -i input.MOV -codec:v libvpx -quality good -cpu-used 0 -b:v 10k
-qmin 10 -qmax 42 -maxrate 10k -bufsize 20k -threads 8 -vf scale=-1:1080
-codec:a libvorbis -b:a 192k
output.webm
```

I want to encode at a couple of different bit rates (video and audio combined):

- 2192 kbps
- 1692 kbps
- 1000 kbps

The problem is that no matter which bit rates I enter, I always get a file with a bit rate higher than 1900 kbps. (1914 kbps with the code example above.)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`libvpx` is a little complicated with regard to rate control and quality settings. Please refer to the [vpx Encoding Guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/vpxEncodingGuide) and the [VP8 Encode Parameter Guide](http://www.webmproject.org/docs/encoder-parameters/) for more info. It took me an hour of digging through the source code to understand it.

If you want to set constant bitrate, you will have to set `b:v`, `maxrate` and `minrate` to the same values, for example like so (note that I left out the audio options here for brevity):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libvpx -b:v 1900K -maxrate 1900K -minrate 1900K output.webm
```

If instead you want to use variable quality and just specify the upper bound for the bitrate, then you need to set both `b:v` and `crf`. If you leave out `crf`, the specified bitrate will just be taken as an average. Only with `crf`, the encoder changes the meaning of `b:v` to the maximum allowed rate.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libvpx -b:v 1900K -crf 10 output.webm
```

A value of 10 for the CRF is a good starting point, but `libvpx` may change the quality per frame within the bounds of `qmin ≤ q ≤ qmax`, which you can also specify if you want. Setting a lower bound of 10  for `qmin` seems a little high to me, but in essence you'll have to do some trial and error anyway, since if the maximum bitrate is too low, you'll constantly saturate it.

Comment: Thank you very much for you time! :) As you said in your first example, leaving out the quality did the trick. It works like a charm now.