# FFmpeg CRF control using x264 vs libvpx-vp9

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, x264, libvpx

I have some experience using ffmpeg with x264 and I wanted to do a comparison with libvpx-vp9. I tested a simple single pass encoding of a raw [video](https://developer.nvidia.com/heavy-hand), varying the crf settings and presets both with x264 and libvpx-vp9. I am new to libvpx and I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761893/why-does-ffmpeg-always-make-large-webm-files/15771867#15771867) and [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8) carefully but I might have still specified wrong combination of parameters since the results I get do not make much sense to me.

For x264 I did:

```
ffmpeg -i test_video.y4m -c:v libx264 -threads 1 -crf <crf> -preset <preset> -y output.mkv
```

and obtained the following results:

```
codec  , settings                        , time        , PSNR      ,bitrate
libx264,['-crf', '20', '-preset', 'fast'],13.1897280216, 42.938337 ,15728
libx264,['-crf', '20', '-preset', 'medium'],16.80494689, 42.879753 ,15287
libx264,['-crf', '20', '-preset', 'slow'],25.1142120361, 42.919206 ,15400
libx264,['-crf', '30', '-preset', 'fast'],8.79047083855, 37.975141 ,4106
libx264,['-crf', '30', '-preset', 'medium'],9.936599016, 37.713778 ,3749
libx264,['-crf', '30', '-preset', 'slow'],13.0959510803, 37.569511 ,3555
```

This makes sense to me, given a crf value you get a value of PSNR and changing the preset can decrease the bitrate but increase the time to encode.

For libvpx-vp9 I did:

```
ffmpeg -i test_video.y4m -c:v libvpx-vp9 -threads 1 -crf <crf> -cpu-used <effort> -y output.mkv
```

First of all I thought from tutorials online that the `-cpu-used` option is equivalent to `-preset` in x264. Is that correct? If so what is the difference with `-quality`? Furthermore since the range goes from -8 to 8 I assumed that negative values where the fast options while positive values the slowest. Results I get are very confusing though:

```
codec     , settings                      , time        , PSNR     ,bitrate
libvpx-vp9,['-crf', '20', '-cpu-used', '-2'],19.6644911766,32.54317,571
libvpx-vp9,['-crf', '20', '-cpu-used', '0'],176.670887947,32.69899,564
libvpx-vp9,['-crf', '20', '-cpu-used', '2'],20.0206270218,32.54317,571
libvpx-vp9,['-crf', '30', '-cpu-used', '-2'],19.7931578159,32.54317,571
libvpx-vp9,['-crf', '30', '-cpu-used', '0'],176.587754965,32.69899,564
libvpx-vp9,['-crf', '30', '-cpu-used', '2'],19.8394429684,32.54317,571
```

Bitrate is very low and PSNR seems unaffected by the `crf` setting (and very low compared to x264). The `-cpu-used` setting has very minimal impact and also seems that -2 and 2 are the same option.. What am I missing? I expected libvpx to take more time to encode (which is definitely true) but at the same time higher quality transcodes. What parameters should I use to 
 have a fair comparison with x264?

**Edit:** Thanks to @mulvya and this [doc](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9) I figured that to work in crf mode with libvpx I have to add `-b:v 0`. I re-ran my tests and I get:

```
    codec     , settings                                 , time        , PSNR     ,bitrate
libvpx-vp9,['-crf', '20', '-b:v', '0', '-cpu-used', '-2'],57.6835780144,45.111158,17908
libvpx-vp9,['-crf', '20', '-b:v', '0', '-cpu-used', '0'] ,401.360313892,45.285367,17431
libvpx-vp9,['-crf', '20', '-b:v', '0', '-cpu-used', '2'] ,57.4941239357,45.111158,17908
libvpx-vp9,['-crf', '30', '-b:v', '0', '-cpu-used', '-2'],49.175855875,42.588178,11085
libvpx-vp9,['-crf', '30', '-b:v', '0', '-cpu-used', '0'] ,347.158324957,42.782194,10935
libvpx-vp9,['-crf', '30', '-b:v', '0', '-cpu-used', '2'] ,49.1892938614,42.588178,11085
```

PSNR and bitrate went up significantly by adding `-b:v 0`

Comment: For VP9, you need to add `-b:v 0` when encoding to CRF.

Comment: Thanks! I will edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative values for `-speed` imply a deadline, but at near-zero speed settings, that has no effect. For faster encodes, use `-speed` values further away from zero (e.g. 4, or 6). You could also consider using threading.

`-quality` is deprecated and should not be used (according to the code comments).

Comment: Hi @Ronald, could you elaborate a little more what you mean when you say that negative speed "imply a deadline"? I ran more tests, varying the crf and speed parameters and I see that negative speed settings produce results equal (in terms of PSNR and bitrate) to a positive speed but takes more time to complete.

Comment: It means there's a timer running to calculate how long it takes to encode each superblock (64x64 pixels), and if that takes longer than a deadline, it will abort encoding and drop the frame. However, you didn't set a deadline, so the default (unlimited) is used, which means it never aborts encoding the frame. So, it runs some extra code (making it slower) but never uses the results from that. Deadline is primarily useful for realtime communication (RTC) applications.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!